# Updating an LP_c_ubyte buffer created in a C DLL

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am creating a Python wrapper for a C DLL using Python ctypes.

In the Python code below I am creating a array `connectionString` of `c_ubyte` that I need to fill int the individual. For example 1,2,3,4,5,6... This connection string is passed to the DLL's `DoCallBack` function and printed. A buffer is created for the callback function to fill in and everything is passed to the python call back function.

1. I am looking for a way to update the `connectionString` bytes before passing them to the DLL's `DoCallBack`.
2. Then how to extract the bytes from the `connectionString` in the python `callbackFnk` function.
3. I am looking for a way to update the bytes in `outBuffer` from the `callbackFnk` python function

A continuation of this question 
[In python how do I set the value of a LP_c_ubyte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033276/in-python-how-do-i-set-the-value-of-a-lp-c-ubyte#50033276)

**C DLL Code**

```
typedef void(*FPCallback)(unsigned char * outBuffer, unsigned short MaxOutBufferLength, unsigned char * connectionString);
FPCallback g_Callback;

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) void RegisterCallback(void(*p_Callback)( unsigned char * outBuffer, unsigned short MaxOutBufferLength, unsigned char * connectionString)) {
    g_Callback = p_Callback ; 
}

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) void DoCallBack( unsigned char connectionString) {
    printf( "connectionString=[%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x...]\n", connectionString[0], connectionString[1], connectionString[2], connectionString[3], connectionString[4], connectionString[5] ); 
    const unsigned short MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 6 ; 
    unsigned char outBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];     

    g_Callback( outBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, connectionString, 6 ); 

    // Print the results. 
    printf( "buffer=[%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x...]\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4], buffer[5] ); 
}
```

**Python code**

```
def callbackFnk( outBuffer, outBufferMaxSize, connectionString )
    # (Q2) How do I extract individual bytes of the connectionString? 
    # (Q3) How do I update individual bytes of the out buffer?     

customDLL = cdll.LoadLibrary ("customeDLL.dll")

# RegisterCallback
CustomDLLCallbackFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER( c_ubyte), c_ushort, POINTER( c_ubyte) )
CustomDLLCallback_func = CustomDLLCallbackFUNC( callbackFnk )
RegisterCallback = customDLL.RegisterCallback
RegisterCallback.argtypes = [ CustomDLLCallbackFUNC ]
RegisterCallback( CustomDLLCallback_func ) 

# DoCallBack
DoCallBack = customDLL.DoCallBack
DoCallBack.argtypes = [ POINTER( c_ubyte) ]

connectionString = c_ubyte(6) 
# (Q1) How do I update this array of bytes? 

# Call the callback 
DoCallBack(connectionString)
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043861/python-ctype-passing-pointer-for-data/50048663#50048663. I did the same thing for `LP_c_float`. `connectionString = (c_ubyte * 6)()`, `DoCallBack(cast(connectionString, POINTER(c_uchar)))`.

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Refer to your last question where I fixed your question to run without changes.  For example, `c_uchar` isn't a `ctypes` type.  Are you manually typing in the code instead of cut-n-paste from your local code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's example has a number of errors and doesn't compile, so I put this together.  I assume `connectionString` is just a nul-terminated input string, and demonstrate updating the output string in the callback.

Note with an *input* string, `c_char_p` can be the type and a Python byte string can be passed.  `c_wchar_p` is used for Python Unicode strings.  The string must not be modified in the C code.  The callback will receive it as a Python string as well, making it easy to read.

The output buffer can just be indexed, being careful to not index past the length of the buffer.  Output buffers allocated by the caller should always be passed as a pointer-and-length.

**C++ DLL**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(const char* string, unsigned char* buffer, size_t size);

CALLBACK g_pCallback;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void RegisterCallback(CALLBACK pCallback) {
    g_pCallback = pCallback;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DoCallBack(char* string) {
    unsigned char buf[6];
    printf("string = %s\n", string);
    g_pCallback(string, buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("buf = [%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x]\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3], buf[4], buf[5]);
}
```

**Python**

```
from ctypes import *

CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None,c_char_p,POINTER(c_ubyte),c_size_t)

@CALLBACK
def callback(string,buf,length):
    print(string)
    for i in range(length):
        buf[i] = i * 2

dll = CDLL('test')

# RegisterCallback
RegisterCallback = dll.RegisterCallback
RegisterCallback.argtypes = [CALLBACK]
RegisterCallback.restype = None
RegisterCallback(callback) 

# DoCallBack
DoCallBack = dll.DoCallBack
DoCallBack.argtypes = [c_char_p]
DoCallBack.restype = None
DoCallBack(b'test string')
```

**Output**

```
string = test string
b'test string'
buf = [00 02 04 06 08 0a]
```

Comment: Thank you, Sorry about the non compiling code. I will strive to do better on my next question.